# Function of infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $f(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^nx(x-1)^n$, then what is $f\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)$?

I tried to reduce it to a predefined infinite series but I was unable to do so.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nx (x-1)^n=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (-1)^n(x-1)^n=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (1-x)^n$$
Let $a=(1-x)$ and then ???

Comment: and then profit!

Comment: ^ chaaaaaching!